# Does "させ" comes from the verb 刺す or just する ?

Tags: grammar, conjugations

Recently I came across this sentence in a computing-related technical document:

> some software と連携させ、 some feature のカスタマイズを作成します。

I get the meaning (after having integrated some product, we will customize some feature), but my question is:

In this sentence, does させ come from the verb 刺す or just する ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

する--or to be more precise, させる.  It is one way to abbreviate させる when used in the middle of a sentence (more commonly you would see させて).

Comment: Not an abbreviation so much as another way to connect words other than ーて

Comment: However, using the -ます stem for transitions is, at times, not the same as using the -て form. The -ます stem transition implies that the preceding action is completed before the succeeding action begins, whereas the -て form can be used to express both this and two actions which overlap, either partially or completely.

Comment: @DerekSchaab, that sounds backwards -- compound verbs, where two verb senses are combined into one action, are essentially [verb 1 in stem form][verb 2], as in 食べきる, 出来上がる, or 追いかける.  The て auxiliary (i.e. verb ending) probably grew out of the 連用形{れんようけい} or continuative form of old perfective auxiliary つ.  See [the Daijirin entry here](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A6) for more.  (Scroll down to the seventh entry, starting with: 完了の助動詞「つ」の連用形からでたものといわれる。)  In other words, て implies that the preceding action is done: [verb 1] *and then* [verb 2].

Answer (score 3):

Just する. 連携する -> 連携させ is correct, 刺す has separate meaning.

Comment: Perfectly valid answer too, but Amanda answered first.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it comes from an old conjugation of す, which led to modern する.　You can see all of its conjugations [here](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B5%E8%A1%8C%E5%A4%89%E6%A0%BC%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8).